# Desktop Launcher doesn't start my app, while terminal does

Tags: command-line, 18.04, permissions, .desktop

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, I've created launchers for different applications but **one** of the launchers **doesn't start** my app, I don't know why, but when I run **the same** command in the terminal it works properly.
The structure of the files `.desktop` is the same.

Here's my launcher `designer.desktop` file which doesn't work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=TIBCO Designer
Exec=/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer
Icon=/TIBCO/tibco/tools/resouces/icons/tibco-icon.png
```

and this is the one working `dbvis.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=DbVisualizer
Exec=/opt/DbVisualizer/dbvis
Icon=/opt/DbVisualizer/resources/images/ix3/dbvis-icon.icns
```

both of them have permissions to be executed `chmod +x *.desktop`

[screenshot showing files permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugsie.png)

When I run this command `/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer` in my terminal it works fine and my application starts successfully

Comment: Please try changing the `Exec` line to `Exec=/bin/bash "/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer"` and report back. Also is this a GUI app?

Comment: still no result, it doesn't show any error message but also no result

Comment: Yes ! it is a GUI app not a script

Comment: Try switching to `Terminal=true`, it might give a clue.

Comment: I tried it but still in the same situation

Comment: What about `Exec=bash -c '/TIBCO/tibco/designer/5.11/bin/designer'`?

Comment: It doesn't work, I really don't how this launcher doesn't work, 2 GUI apps i can say with the same launcher but just of them is working

Comment: Sorry, I'm also out of ideas :(

Comment: @pomsky thanks for your time ! I really appreciate your help

Comment: `/TIBCO/tibco/....` is not a valid directory for a .desktop file. `/opt` obviously is a full path. Terminal reads from current working directory, that's why it works.

Comment: `/TIBCO/tibco/...` is also a full path, if it's not a valid directory for a `.desktop` file, I don't know about, and I cannot change it

Comment: Are you saying you created /TIBCO in the root directory? Guess not.

Comment: No, `/TIBCO/tibco/...` is the full path so my app is under `/` not `/root`, the is that i can run the same command in terminal but when i make a launcher for my app providing the same command, it doesn't work

Comment: Check this answer if it helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237042/desktop-files-not-launching-from-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1256301#answer-1256301