# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Disappeared

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, desktop-icons

Although the PC still runs well and the Desktop folder is there and has everything in it, the icons that were on the actual visible desktop have disappeared. I realized that some of the environments don't have desktop icons but this wasn't one of them unless it somehow changed itself between boots. They were there, then after a reboot they were all gone. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182917/desktop-folder-and-files-disappeared) talks about a similar but not identical issue and its ideas do not seem to apply to mine. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the Gnome desktop icon extension got removed. Could you check whether the solution 1 works? https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/re-enable-desktop-icons-in-gnome-shell/ If it does, I will present it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you and seems that’s what happened. I’m away now but once I return I’ll see if it fixes the problem, then I’ll report back.

Comment: Checkout the answer if it helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237042/desktop-files-not-launching-from-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1256301#answer-1256301

Comment: This PC is apparently running xfce so none of the above helped and I found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop . I don't recall ever installing a desktop other than Gnome but apparently I did!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, too. Suddenly all my icons on the desktop were gone. After a long search I found that for me the reason was a change in the file: `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Schreibtisch"
#XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Vorlagen"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Öffentlich"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Dokumente"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Musik"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Bilder"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

In the line `#XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"` the word `Schreibtisch` (Desktop in German) was missing.

Hope that this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post. I am not so good in English, sorry.