# Add an app to the launcher

Tags: gnome, java, launcher

I'm using ImageJ, which is distributed as a folder with Java files. I would like to add it to the app launcher. Unfortunately instructions from: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux don't work. Right clicking on ImageJ icon on the desktop doesn't show `Allow Launching` option. What is the solution?

**NOTE 1**

I found that copying the executable file to Desktop folder wasn't the way to go. In app directory:

```
paul@desktop:~/apps/Fiji.app$ ls
Contents   ImageJ2.desktop  images  java  licenses  macros   README.md  scripts
db.xml.gz  ImageJ-linux64   jars    lib   luts      plugins  retro      WELCOME.md
```

there `ImageJ2.desktop` file suitable for this purpose. Right clicking on it shows `Allow Launching` option. Unfortunately, selecting it doesn't make it visible to the Gnome app launcher.

Comment: Do [any of the answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1237042/desktop-files-not-launching-from-desktop-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts) solve your issue? 

Comment: @matigo I tried most of them, except the ones I couldn't understand, and no cigar. They are relying on "Allow Launching" option to be visible, and it is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the command line to launch the software from the terminal,
I suggest using 'Menu editor' available in the Software center to resolve your issue - adding the launcher to the Gnome apps.

For example

The command line for opening ImageJ that is extracted to my 'Home' folder is `java -jar /home/dr/ij153-linux64-java8/ImageJ/ij.jar` 
The above command shall be used to create the launcher using the Menu editor.

Comment: I tried it. *Test Launcher* button fails to launch the app.

Comment: @Jurczak, I have edited the answer